# How to compare json object with the document having same value store in mongodb using java

Tags: java, xml, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to compare json with the document having same values in MongoDb. But it returns false whether both are same or not.

So guys,let me help

I have given details about my code to get help you.

```
**//comparison code**
                DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json4);

                boolean val=collection.equals(dbObject);

                System.out.println(val);
                System.out.println(dbObject);

**//document stored into 'dummyColl' collection**
> db.dummyColl.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : "11",
        "xml" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><tr
ansperfect><DEV id=\"11\"><lastname>yong11</lastname><nickname>mook kim11</nickn
ame><salary>mkyong11</salary><permanentAddress>10000011</permanentAddress><curre
ntAddress>Bhopal11</currentAddress><contactNo>pune11</contactNo><email>999999999
11</email><alternateMail>test11@basex.com</alternateMail><FacebookName>testA11@b
asex.com</FacebookName><Color>Tom11</Color></DEV></transperfect>"

**//json to compare with document stored into 'dummyColl' collection**
{ "_id" : "11" , "xml" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><transperfect><DEV id=\"11\"><lastname>yong11</lastname><nickname>mook kim11</nickname><salary>mkyong11</salary><permanentAddress>10000011</permanentAddress><currentAddress>Bhopal11</currentAddress><contactNo>pune11</contactNo><email>99999999911</email><alternateMail>test11@basex.com</alternateMail><FacebookName>testA11@basex.com</FacebookName><Color>Tom11</Color></DEV></transperfect>"}
```

Comment: This is honestly not the right approach.  You should not be mixing "data representation" in the document storage. Don't embed XML but rather covert to JSON and then you can "reap the benefits" of MongoDB queries. Mongo just sees a string here.

Comment: @Neil Lunn yes i am doing the same as you thought. I am converting the xml into json and then i am storing into mongodb.

Comment: @Neil Lunn see the output it shows the document in json format

Comment: The document is JSON/BSON because it has to be. But you a storing an XML string, which is essentially wrong. That is the data you should be coverting

Comment: @Neil Lunn if i am missing something so please can you provide me some examples how to store xml into mongodb? See the code below where i am using the way to store xml into mongodb.                              **String json3 = "{'_id':'"+id+"','xml':'"+xmlFile+"'}";   
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json3);
collection.insert(dbObject);**